# How to Increment the Push notification Badge iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios8, apple-push-notifications

Is it possible to increment the badge value on receiving the notification. OR Should I send the count as **payload**?

If i am sending the badge value as "1" every time, how could i increment the **badge-value** in the icon of the app if the app is not open.

I used this code but doesn't work.

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber + 1; 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to change the icon badge automatically use the following code.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{

    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
    NSLog(@"userInfo %@",userInfo);

    for (id key in userInfo) {
        NSLog(@"key: %@, value: %@", key, [userInfo objectForKey:key]);
    }

    [application setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:[[[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey:@"badge"] intValue]];

    NSLog(@"Badge %d",[[[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey:@"badge"] intValue]);

}
```

We also need to change the php file. So we can get the change the icon badge automatically

```
// Create the payload body
$body['aps'] = array(
    'alert' => $message,
    'sound' => 'default',
    'id' => '135',
    'badge' => 8
    );
```

Comment: can you have it autoincrement rather than taking a badge value from the notification payload (if the server can't calculate unread count?)

Answer (score 0):

Since push notification are handled by iOS and not your app you can't change the application badge on receiving a push notification.

But you can send the badge number in the payload of the push notification, but the you will have to do the calculation server side.

You should read :Local and Push Notification Programming Guide and specially the The Notification Payload.

The payload could look like this:

{
    "aps" : {
        "alert" : "You got your emails.",
        "badge" : 9
    }
}
Now the app application badge icon will show 9.